# What set is the head in this MOC from?

Tags: part-identification, moc, bionicle, hero-factory

This MOC uses some kind of armour for the head and possibly the thighs. I thought it was Hero Factory but I couldn’t find it on Bricklink.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help in identifying it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Hero Factory Weapon Accessory - Machinery Armor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=99358) is the part you are looking for.

[image]